# Does shunt calibration of a sensor also correct for zero error?

Tags: sensor, measurement, load-cell, calibration, strain-gage

In the datasheet for a load cell (shown below), it says that shunt calibration data is given, also they have mentioned the zero balance. Does the shunt calibration consider zero balance? Meaning, do I need to calibrate for the zero error separately? I couldn't find any direct information on this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You null **offset error** first.

Then calibrate gain or null **gain error** with the shunt. Load reference R…

This is standard for all ADC’s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would really appreciate if you could clarify two things for me. Is offset nulling also done by using the same potentiometer used for shunt calibration? Additionally, does the offset error also take into account errors due to resistor tolerances? I am essentially trying to carry out an error budgeting for my system and wish to know if I should consider offset due to resistor tolerance in addition to the tolearance value mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: There are always separate adjustments for offset and gain error of the system including the bridge. How that is done is unique to the system.

Answer (score 0):

No, applying the shunt resistance causes the specified *change* in the output.